# Spring Boot Demo Not Running

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to run the Spring Boot getting started example. https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/.
I really like this framework however the issue below is really frustrating.

My pom.xml is exactly as listed in the demo

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.warn(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:179)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.callFinishedListener(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:91)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.finished(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:810)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
at com.testing.Application.main(Application.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

And the only class in the project:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Finally
[a screenshot of the Libraries IntelliJ is listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuYFw.png)

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.2 with built in maven 3.0.5.
I have run maven clean, deleted .m2 and got a fresh repo, uninstalled IntelliJ and so much more. Please do not say it is a "logging framework incompatibility"; I have tried just about every SO post that mentions that and no luck.

UPDATE: as suggested, I have cloned the project directly from GitHub and attempted to run using spring-boot:run plugin. Still the same exception. I am at a complete loss, I have no idea how to proceed.

UPDATE: 
result of mvn dependency:tree --debug

```
constituent[0]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/aether-       api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[1]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/aether- connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[2]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/aether-impl- 1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[3]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[4]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[5]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
constituent[6]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
constituent[7]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[8]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
constituent[9]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
constituent[10]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
constituent[11]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
constituent[12]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/guava-18.0.jar
constituent[13]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/guice-4.0-no_aop.jar
constituent[14]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[15]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar
constituent[16]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[17]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar
constituent[18]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar
constituent[19]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar
constituent[20]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-compat-3.3.9.jar
constituent[21]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-core-3.3.9.jar
constituent[22]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-embedder-3.3.9.jar
constituent[23]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar
constituent[24]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar
constituent[25]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.3.9.jar
constituent[26]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar
constituent[27]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-settings-3.3.9.jar
constituent[28]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.3.9.jar
constituent[29]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.2.jar
constituent[30]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.2.jar
constituent[31]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[32]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
constituent[33]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
constituent[34]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
constituent[35]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
constituent[36]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
constituent[37]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
constituent[38]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/wagon-file-2.10.jar
constituent[39]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/wagon-http-2.10-shaded.jar
constituent[40]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/wagon-http-shared-2.10.jar
constituent[41]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.10.jar
constituent[42]: file:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/logging/
```

Comment: So far both of the answers sound like problems with the Spring Boot dependency management which I have a hard time believing based on the testing that is done on it. This really sounds like an IntelliJ IDE problem in relation to the project. I would hate for you to have to modify your project to support your IDE. Going to install IntelliJ and see what is happening.

Comment: Steps I took...

1) Installed IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.2.1
2) On the project start screen chose to clone the getting started repo
3) Created a project based on the `/complete` directory from the repo
4) Created maven run profile with `spring-boot:run`
5) Ran project and it ran successfully.

I checked my project dependencies compared to yours and I had a few more. I am guessing you went through and manually created your project from the page? Try using the `complete` project to start to verify that it does work. Then need to go back and see what you did different than the complete.

Comment: How do you run the application? Do you run it as a Java application, a Spring boot application or do you use Maven? I'm using the same version of IntelliJ, using the same code, having the same library listing and I can run the application perfectly.

Comment: The class path has a mixture of SLF4J jar with different versions which means that the libraries listed by IntelliJ don't match what's actually on the class path. As @g00glen00b asked, know how you run the application would help. Also, the output of running with `-verbose:class` would show from where the various classes are being loaded.

Comment: shawn great suggestion I will give this a try. @g00glen00b I have been running the application by clicking the green play button in the main class. This is running it as a maven project.

Comment: @ShawnClark cloned the demo as you suggested. Ran with spring:boot-run and still the exact same exception. So frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Wow finally figured this out. So relieved. Thanks to @Andy Wilkinson, I added -verbose:class as a VM option in IntelliJ. I found that I had some jar files behind pulled in outside my maven repo. Specifically, Xuggler was pulling in all sorts of logging and slf4j jars that conflicted with maven pulling in 1.7.21. 
Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score -2):

Add following dependencies in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you should explicitly config the latest apache common logging in your pom.xml because it's the default slf4j implementation used by Spring. 
[image]

Comment: This is a very insightful suggestion, the best one I have received. Can you please explicitly state what I need to add to my pom.xml?

Comment: Since you've added logback in your pom, just exclude common-logging and use logback as the implememtation of slf4j.

Comment: refer to: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-log-in-spring-with-slf4j-and-logback/